# On plotting multiple lists

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have four lists as given below:

```
 l1 = {r1 -> 0.1, r2 -> 0.3, r3 -> 0.1, r4 -> 1.0, r5 -> 0.3, 
   r6 -> 0.1};
l2 = {r1 -> 0.3, r2 -> 0.9, r3 -> 0.5, r4 -> 0.1, r5 -> 0.2, 
   r6 -> 0.2};
l3 = {r1 -> 0.4, r2 -> 0.1, r3 -> 0.2, r4 -> 0.2, r5 -> 0.7, 
   r6 -> 0.3};
l4 = {r1 -> 0.5, r2 -> 0.63, r3 -> 0.4, r4 -> 0.4, r5 -> 0.5, 
   r6 -> 0.4};
```

Is there an easy way to show how (`r1`, `r2`,`r3`,`r4`, `r5`) change respect to  `r6` ? I am in practice, dealing with large number of such lists, but the variables are just six.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
l1 = {r1 -> 0.1, r2 -> 0.3, r3 -> 0.1, r4 -> 1.0, r5 -> 0.3, 
   r6 -> 0.1};
l2 = {r1 -> 0.3, r2 -> 0.9, r3 -> 0.5, r4 -> 0.1, r5 -> 0.2, 
   r6 -> 0.2};
l3 = {r1 -> 0.4, r2 -> 0.1, r3 -> 0.2, r4 -> 0.2, r5 -> 0.7, 
   r6 -> 0.3};
l4 = {r1 -> 0.5, r2 -> 0.63, r3 -> 0.4, r4 -> 0.4, r5 -> 0.5, 
   r6 -> 0.4};

lists = {l1, l2, l3, l4};
plots = Transpose[{r6 /. lists, # /. lists}] & /@ {r1, r2, r3, r4, r5};
ListLinePlot[plots]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Syed, could you explain here this step in words : Transpose[{r6 /. lists, # /. lists}] & /@ {r1, r2, r3, r4, r5}

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end to see what `plots` looks like. Here `/@` is the  `Map` command. So we create tuples for each of the point to be plotted in the list changing with respect to `r6`.

Answer (score 6):

You can also construct a [`TemporalData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) object from `l`:

```
l = Values @ {l1, l2, l3, l4};

td = TemporalData[Most /@ l, {Last /@ l},
   "MetaInformation" ->
    {"ComponentNames" -> {"col 1", "col 2", "col 3", "col 4", "col 5"}}];

ListLinePlot[td, PlotLegends -> td[ "ComponentNames"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
l = Values @ {l1, l2, l3, l4};

ListLinePlot[Transpose @ Map[Thread @ {Last @ #, Most @ #} &] @ l, 
 PlotLegends -> Range[Length @ l]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do not use numbered variable names because it is not easy to use them. Better, put the data in an array like e.g.:

```
l0 = {r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6};
l=Table[{},4];
l[[1]] = 
  l0 /. {r1 -> 0.1, r2 -> 0.3, r3 -> 0.1, r4 -> 1.0, r5 -> 0.3, r6 -> 0.1};
l[[2]] = 
  l0 /. {r1 -> 0.3, r2 -> 0.9, r3 -> 0.5, r4 -> 0.1, r5 -> 0.2, r6 -> 0.2};
l[[3]] = 
  l0 /. {r1 -> 0.4, r2 -> 0.1, r3 -> 0.2, r4 -> 0.2, r5 -> 0.7, r6 -> 0.3};
l[[4]] = 
  l0 /. {r1 -> 0.5, r2 -> 0.63, r3 -> 0.4, r4 -> 0.4, r5 -> 0.5, r6 -> 0.4};
```

Then you can easily assemble the data for a ListPlot:

```
d = Table[{l[[j, 6]], l[[j, i]]}, {i, 5}, {j, 4}]
ListLinePlot[d]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel Huber. When I run your code, it says:  Set: Symbol l in part assignment does not have an immediate value.

Comment: You are right, I forget to pre-assign l. I fixed it.